# Filtering datas by user id and dates between - Spring Boot

Tags: mysql, spring, api, spring-security

I'm trying to make a todo application on Spring. It's almost finished but I got a problem. I need to filter todos by user id and select them which is in the between given dates. I've created a method for this in my TodoRepository. But when I send the request to the url, it gives me empty array.

Here's the repository class:

All methods work fine except the one I mentioned btw.

```
@Repository
public interface TodoRepository extends JpaRepository<Todo, Long> {
    List<Todo> findTodosByUserId(Long id);

    List<Todo> findTodosByUserIdOrderByDateAsc(String id);

    List<Todo> findAllByDateBetween(Date date, Date date2);

    List<Todo> findTodosByDateBetweenAndUserId(Date date, Date date2, Long id);
}
```

That's the method i use in the TodoService class:

```
@Service
public class TodosService {

    @Autowired
    TodoRepository todoRepository;

   //other methods..

    public List<Todo> filterTodosByUserId(FilterTodoByUserDto dto){
        Date date1 = dto.getDate1();
        Date date2 = dto.getDate2();
        Long id = dto.getId();
        return todoRepository.findTodosByDateBetweenAndUserId(date1, date2, id);
    }

}
```

FilterTodoByUserDto class:

```
public class FilterTodoByUserDto {

    private Long id;
    private Date date1;
    private Date date2;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Date getDate1() {
        return date1;
    }

    public void setDate1(Date date1) {
        this.date1 = date1;
    }

    public Date getDate2() {
        return date2;
    }

    public void setDate2(Date date2) {
        this.date2 = date2;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "FilterTodoByUserDto{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", date1=" + date1 +
                ", date2=" + date2 +
                '}';
    }
}
```

And lastly, controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class TodoController {

    @Autowired
    private TodosService todosService;

    //other methods..

    @GetMapping("user/todos/filter")
    public List<Todo> filterTodosById(@RequestBody FilterTodoByUserDto dto){
        List<Todo> todos = todosService.filterTodosByUserId(dto);
        return todos;
    }

    //other methods..

}
```

Request body that i sent with postman:

```
{"userId":"1", "date1":"2021-01-01", "date2":"2000-01-01"}
```

Database output:

```
mysql> select * from todos;
+----+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| id | date                       | description | todo_status | user_id |
+----+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|  1 | 2012-12-12 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | TODO        |       2 |
|  2 | 2010-10-10 00:00:00.000000 | deneme2     | TODO        |       2 |
|  3 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme5     | DONE        |       1 |
|  4 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       1 |
|  5 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       1 |
|  6 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       1 |
|  7 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       1 |
|  8 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       1 |
|  9 | 2010-01-01 00:00:00.000000 | deneme      | DONE        |       2 |
+----+----------------------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
9 rows in set (0,01 sec)
```

Comment: `date` `date1` `date2` all look quite similar - easy to confuse, so review your code carefully. Also, there are very few dates that  are greater than 2021 and less than 2020.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your request **`json` like this:**

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "date1": "2000-01-01",
    "date2": "2021-01-01"
}
```

Your fields in your `DTO` model **should match your `json` fields**. (`userId` -> `id`)

`BETWEEN` returns true if the value of `date` is greater than or equal to the value of *begin_expression* and less than or equal to the value of *end_expression*. `(.. date BETWEEN date1 AND date2)`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting empty array due to your postman request is logically wrong. When BETWEEN use date1 must be the minimum value and date2 must be the maximum value.

ex: The following date example uses the BETWEEN condition to retrieve values within a date range.

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM todos
    where user_id=1
    and date between '2000-01-01' and '2021-01-01';
```

Above BETWEEN SQL would be equivalent to the following SELECT statement:

```
    SELECT * 
    FROM todos
    where user_id=1
    and date >= '2000-01-01' and  date<= '2021-01-01';
```